# How do I replace the <> charactes with sed in a cmd script in windows? They are interpreted as redirection operators

Tags: regex, sed, cmd

I want to create a big html file from many small html files. They use only basic tags (h1-h4, p, br, hr, span), all of it manually written. Comments appear just in 2 or 3 places.

What I want: I want to replace the string `<!--css-->` with something (e.g., qwerty), using sed (cygwin). Trying to understand the error, I reduced the command to this (written in a .cmd file):

```
sed.exe -i -r -z 's,<!--css-->,qwerty,g' outfile
```

(nothing is replaced)

```
sed.exe -i -r -z 's,\x3c!--css--\x3e,qwerty,g' outfile
```

(nothing happens again)

```
sed.exe -i -r -z 's,!--css--,qwerty,g' outfile
```

(result is `<qwerty>` - but I do not need the angle brackets)

Options -r, -z, -e in any combination make no difference

I am not yet familiar with *nix scripts, so I would not like to go there.

PS: I used sed for many other things and it worked - it just chokes with the angle brackets (or Windows / cmd does).

sample file:

```
bla1 bla2

<!--css-->

bla3 bla4
```

Comment: If you can't get rid of Windows entirely, a common workaround is to put your `sed` script in a file and run it with `sed -f filename`

Comment: `^` is how you do that.

Comment: If you are under command prompt, use double qutoes instead of `'`.

Comment: @tripleee: I thought of that, but my ego tries to avoid too many files, thanks

Comment: @Tiw: i tried single quotes and double quotes, no use :(

Comment: Single quotes mean nothing to cmd.exe. You need double quotes.

Comment: @catcat: I do not understand - is the carret ^ a special character for sed, or you just say that previous comment is the good one?

Comment: `^` is the escape character in cmd.exe.

Comment: @melpomene: I just tried again with double quotes - nohing

Comment: Why are you using `-z`?

Comment: sed.exe -i -r -z "s,^<!--css--^>,qwerty,g" outfile does not work. In other instances, I need to handle multi-line replacements - it changes nothing anyway - not in this case.

Comment: In Windows, you can escape the special characters `<` and `>` by `^<` and `^>`, respectively; when they appear in between a pair of `"` (double-quotes), no such escaping is necessary...

Comment: Since the I cannot mark a comment as a solution - which would be fair, I will mark my answer as the solution. Tnx everyone for helping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Tiw helped me understand the abomination. Tnx ;)

Unfortunately, command prompt (regardless of OS) is not an option - not in my current task.

These do NOT work:

```
sed.exe -i -r "s,<!--css-->,qwerty,g" outfile
sed.exe -i -r "s,^<!--css--^>,qwerty,g" outfile
```

But this one does:

```
sed.exe -i -r "s,<^!--css-->,qwerty,g" outfile
```

Also this:

```
sed.exe -i -r "s,^<^!--css--^>,qwerty,g" outfile
```

So the culprit was the exclamation mark! Unbelievable!

Thank you people.

Comment: Wait, so how were you running your code? With bash or with cmd?

Comment: Environment: Windows 7 Enterpsise, 64 bit, SP1, .cmd file with several commands, one of them being this replacement. I just edit the .cmd file in notepad++ (irrelevant, I would assume), and run it in a cmd.exe window. As to why, I have no idea - I just noticed the results.

Comment: In `cmd`, when you have [delayed expansion](http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html) enabled, exclamation marks become a special meaning and must be escaped (`^!`, if in between `""`, or `^^!` otherwise) in order to be treated as literal characters...

Comment: @aschipfl: you are right, because of the rest of the script I have enabled the delayed expansion. Your explanation makes all the sense now. Unfortunately, I cannot give a thumb up to anyone... not yet

Comment: What about disabling delayed expansion just to execute the `sed.exe` command line (`setlocal DisableDelayedExpansion` before, `endlocal` after)? or do you need it for this (for example, it is placed in a code block and receives variables which are also set therein)?

Comment: In other parts of the scripts I have sed + variables which require delayed expansion, so disabling delayed expansion is not always an option. Also, I was not aware of this before I found a working solution - delayed expansion is very new to me - so it is not yet a part of my current thinking.

Answer (score 1):

With file like this:

```
$ cat file.txt
bla1 bla2

<!--css-->

bla3 bla4
```

Under Command Prompt you use this:

```
> sed -r -z "s,<!--css-->,qwerty,g" file.txt
bla1 bla2

qwerty

bla3 bla4
```

Under cygwin bash you use this:

```
$ sed -r -z "s,<\!--css-->,qwerty,g" file.txt
bla1 bla2

qwerty

bla3 bla4
```

Not sure which, this will work on both:

```
sed -r -z "s,<\!--css-->,qwerty,g"
```

Btw, you can just `-rzi` (put `i` last or it will create backup file(s)), no need to separate them on GNU sed. And the `z` is not used I think.

When using single quotes `'` in cmd you need escape `<` and `>` with `^` like this:

```
e:\tmp>sed -rz 's,^<\!--css--^>,qwerty,g' file.txt
bla1 bla2

qwerty

bla3 bla4
```

Comment: The `-irz` does not work as is - but I am aware of the concept. In this particular case, the `rz` is considered as suffix for `-i`. I did not know for a while why I had my files duplicated, some ending in `rz`. Otherwise, good points, as mentioned previously.

Comment: @virolino  Ahh... yep, should be `-zri`. The `i` at last position. Thanks for bring this up :)

Comment: I had exactly that in mind (the -zri), but I was too lazy to test :D